# What is the larva in these nectarines?

Tags: identification, pest-control, pests, nectarines

My family's nectarine tree has been infested with these small larvae, so far I've only seen one per fruit across several dozen fruits, that seem to bore their way from the surface towards the pit and then leave a bunch of droppings near the pit. What are they and how can we get rid of them?

**Specimen 1**
[image: surface hole of nectarine with droppings scattered about]
[image: Closeup of larva and the flesh of the fruit cut just beneath the hole.]
[image: coloring of larva under camera flash]
[image: Cross section of bore dug out by larvae]
**Specimen 2**
[image: larger larva in a second fruit.]
[image: the larva alongside the cut upon fruit to show the trash heap it leaves by the pit.]

Comment: You got it again!  Man just make it an answer...This is just gross to find in a juicy nectarine.  See all the fracas in that first picture?  Can't even eat around it....nicely done.  Ugh!!!

Comment: Heck YOU answered I elaborated...the OP should decide to give you the dang points you silly!  Or can I just 'send' you the points back?  Points are nice I guess but following you around makes me feel like I'm cheating?  Grins!  I had a little discussion with hubby over what IMO meant.  Are we that out of it?  And love opinionated people...but tacky?  Plain jane clay pot feet are tacky?  So did you like that Victorian Cachepot with all the flowers and silver and its probably something its owner should put away when I come to visit!

Comment: I always have extra tiles to use.  Just needs to be a quarter inch off the surface.  I also hate mass produced anything.  There is so much STUFF in the world that isn't brand new and unique. So very much more fun to be creative and find treasures!

Comment: @jxramos Did that information about not allowing the fruit to stay on the ground, raking up debris make any sense for your tree?  Please let us know if we can clarify anything.  Also, I'd think about a professional to go out and prune and help identify other ways to prevent your fruit being ruined.  And help your tree live a long time.  Perhaps a picture of the tree and environment would help us understand more of what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[common nectarine problem insects](http://www.dpi.nsw.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0017/307151/Common-insect-pests-of-nectarines.pdf)  All I know is I will forever be looking before biting into a nectarine or peach or apricot again!!

Pretty sure you've got more than one insect in that fruit.  Pnuts is correct for that gross larva; [Peach Twig Borer](http://fruitandnuteducation.ucdavis.edu/files/154358.jpg).  Wasn't listed in the bulletin I sent but you might check out the beetle and the thrip.  Ugh.  Tell me you didn't bite into this nectarine!

The Bulletin is excellent about how to deal with the insects it talks about but the preventative measures I think would apply for all insects.  There are also beneficials you could use that actually control the numbers of insects very well.

Here is another Bulletin: [Peach Twig Borer](https://climate.usurf.usu.edu/includes/pestFactSheets/Peach-Twig-Borer.pdf)